# Remove login items from old profile that no longer exists, after Time Machine restore

Tags: time-machine, login-items, profile-manager, configuration-profiles

I recently had my work MacBook Pro's admin software removed (by IT, the same department that initially set them up) and the macOS freshly installed, with the old profiles removed. I had a Time Machine backup of the computer and (maybe stupidly) restored the laptop's settings from this backup.

The old profiles that were managed by IT have been removed, but there are still some "login items" that remain. My guess is that I "restored" these login items when restoring from the time machine backup. The login items say that "this setting has been configured by a profile" but when I look at "Profiles" in system settings I don't see any profiles.

Assuming that I somehow reinstalled these items, how would I go about removing them?

[image: Profiles pane with no profiles installed.]

[image: Login items pane, with login items which say "configured by a profile"]